# Tag a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have the following scenario:

- Continuous Delivery with Docker
- Build Image from GitHub repository
- Stop the current running container
- Start the current running container with the newer image

For stopping the container, I need the container ID. 
Can I assign a reusable tag to a container once I start it, so I know which container to stop, once a newer image is ready for deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker run --name "ContainerID" ..... See [here](http://blog.docker.com/2013/10/docker-0-6-5-links-container-naming-advanced-port-redirects-host-integration/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical equation is `rename`:
`docker rename container_id new_name`