# How to tag a docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm creating an app when I have several kind of containers, and I want to know if docker has some way of tagging *containers* (example: database, data-only ...).

Note: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985229/tag-a-docker-container) is about giving names to containers instead of tags. **I'm asking to giving arbitrary tags to containers, not images**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create multiple tag docker image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928780/create-multiple-tag-docker-image)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you may be confusing some Docker terminology.   Here's a brief list of similar-yet-confusing terms

- **Repository** -- a name for a set of images such as 'nginx'
- **Image** -- one binary image such with an id such as 407195ab8b07
- **Tag** -- a user-defined name for 407195ab8b07 such as 'nginx:1.9.9'
- **Container** -- a runnable process the executes the image
- **Label** -- a user-defined name/value pair for an image or container

An image can have many tags and labels -- but these are set **AT BUILD TIME**

Think of an image as a CD or DVD disk for your Xbox -- its a bunch of binary information.

Many containers can be run for an image -- each container runs in its own virtual process and has its own file system, environment.

Think of the container as a Video Game playing on your Xbox -- it's moving and "running" -- a container "runs" an image.  So to create the image you say `docker run` and give it the name of the image to run

```
docker run nginx:1.9.9
```

Containers can be named **when they are created**

```
docker run --name MyNginx nginx:1.9.9
```

The container name can be used to stop the container:

```
docker stop MyNginx
```

Containers can also have labels added at start-time

```
docker run --label "foo=BAR" nginx:1.9.9
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, labeling a container is what I need! (I didn't know it exists)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible with docker commit, as documentation says..

> Create a new image from a container’s changes

Checkout reference in..

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

```
docker commit [CONTAINER_ID]  [REPOSITORY]/[TAG]
```

Comment: I don't think that this answer is correct. As the documentation that you link to says, the `docker commit` command creates a new image and tags the new image. IAmJulianAcosta says in his question that he wants to tag containers, **not images** so you cannot use `docker commit`